# Error while saving output to xlsx file

Tags: java, excel, maven

while running a code that saves the content of a StringBuilder to .xlsx file, It gives me the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.poi.util.POILogger.log(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.buildPartName(ZipPackage.java:275)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:214)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:673)
>     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:274)
>     at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:258)

for the following statement:

```
Workbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
```

I am using maven, and added the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.8-beta3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also, I imported all the necessary classes to deal with Excel files.

I do not know how to solve this problem. I need your help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed. I changed the POI version. I used the following dependency:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.14-beta1</version>
    </dependency>
```